# HTTP header to prevent browser from loading page?

Tags: php, http, mime-types, content-type

I have a php script that takes a file's id in the url, finds the link for the file from an sql database, and then streams the file.

On the client's page, they click a link and are then prompted to download a file. If the file wasn't in the database, I would like to prevent the browser from changing the page to a 404 or other type of error page, but rather keep the client's page where it is.

Is there an HTTP status or content-type that will tell the browser to not load the page? Would doing something like setting the content-length to 0 work?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to use `file_exists()`, and if the file doesn't exist, don't stream it in the first place?

Comment: @Billthelizard I'm very disappointed you deleted my answer; its intension was to show that there was an opportunity to prevent bad links in the first place, instead of processing the error when it happens. Don't catch the exception; Avoid the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
204 No Content
```

Return that status code, and the browser will stay on the page it was on.

Comment: Additional HTTP codes if necessary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: The only thing I'd add to this is to ensure that all supported browsers work, or at least fail honourably without mucking up your page.